# Streaming video with vlc as mjpeg from the RPI

Tags: camera, raspicam, streaming-video

I have an RPI camera module V2 connected to my PI and can stream footage from it into the lan with

```
raspivid -vf -hf -o - -t 0 -w 1000 -h 576 -fps 20 -b 500000 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{access=udp,sdp=rtsp://:8554/stream}' :demux=h264
```

The problem is that I cannot use this stream in the linux Motion software, since it requires for the video stream to be in an MJPEG format. 
How can I change the command above, so it streams in MJPEG?

The vlc manual page says to use a value vcodec=MJPEG, but playing around with it and trying to put it in various places, I never got it to work.

To be more precise, I need the stream in a format which will work with various IP camera management softwares, such as Blue Iris.

Thanks!

Comment: google search resulted in https://gist.github.com/marc-hanheide/7b3557f487f1353b2b7c ... and https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=54066 ...

Comment: Though, I've seen mention that raspivid has "mjpeg goodness" built in ... i.e. `raspivid --codec MJPEG ...`

Comment: I have already encountered and tried that result you posted but I couldnt get it to work (i tried many variations with the transcode and such), I am thinking that I am formatting the command wrongly, so I need someone who knows more about vlc than I to post the corrected command.

Comment: As for the raspivid --codec MJEPG, it is the same problem, I don't know how to implement it into the command above for it to actually work. If i just add the parameter  --codec MJEPG -vf -hf ...  after raspivid then it doesnt work

Comment: 1) "it doesnt work" please add the full error message. 2) "how to implement it into the command" like JaromandaX wrote: add the parameter `--codec` and its value `MJPEG` after the command `raspivid`. 3) To get verbose information during run, add `--verbose`. Try `raspivid --codec MJPEG --verbose -vf -hf -o - -t 0 -w 1000 -h 576 -fps 20 -b 500000 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{access=udp,sdp=rtsp://:8554/stream}' :demux=h264`. Please post the result. Maybe helpful: `raspivid --help` and https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md